# Did Ravaan kill Surpanakha's husband?

Tags: ramayana, rama, ravana, lokas, valmiki

While scrolling through Surpanakha's page on Wikipedia, there it was written that Ravaan had eaten Surpanakha's husband (Vidyutjiva)

Here is a part of the page ---------

> At the time of conquering Rasatala (the underworld), her brother,
> Ravana decided to visit his newly married sister, where he discovered
> Vidyutjihva's true motive to marry Shurpanakha – to kill Ravana. In
> Shurpanakha's absence, Vidyutjihva attacked Ravana, who in
> self-defense killed his brother-in-law.

Even this is written --------

> Some versions of the Ramayana claim that Shurpanakha had no real
> romantic interest in the brothers, engineering Ravana's death in
> revenge for her husband Vidyujjihva's murder. After many years of
> plotting his downfall, she realized that Ravana had more than a match
> in Rama, who had killed both her brothers, Khara and Dushana who
> confronted Rama and Lakshamaņa after they were told of insult to
> Shurpanakha's fate by the duo. Her cousins were terrified of Rama, so
> Shurpanakha decided to pit her brother against Rama, knowing only that
> he was powerful enough to slay her brother.

**So, are the above ture and should be believed ??**

Comment: Please don't create new accounts while you are in suspension. Please wait for the suspension period to be over. If you create new accounts within the suspension period then that only will increase the duration of the ban.

Answer (score 5):

Yes Ravana killed his sister's husband.

As per [this chapter](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-23) of **Valmiki Ramayana: Uttar Kanda**:

> And then going to the city named Asma ruled by the Kalakayas, Ravana() slew the Kalakayas endowed with terriffic striength ;and **then with his sword cut of his brother.in law, the husband of Surpanakha**, the mighty Vidyujjihva possessed of terriffic strength; as that Rakshasa in the encounter was licking (the limbs of Ravana s followers). Having vanquished him, he, in a moment, destroyed four hundred Daityas.

This is further clarified by Ravana to his sister in [this chapter](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-29) of **Valmiki Ramayana: Uttar Kanada**:

> In the interval, Ravana s sister, a dreadful and grim visaged Rakshasi, suddenly fell down on to the ground. And having raised up his sister and consoled her Ravana said "Tell me speedily, O good sister, what you wish to say.
>
> Thereat that Rakshasi, having blood red eyes, closed with tears, said "O king, by thee, powerful as thou art, I have forcibly been made a widow. Fourteen thousand Daityas, under the name of Kalakeyas, have been destroyed by thee, O king, in the battle and amongst them was my highly power ful husband dearer than my life. **He has been slain by thee, O dear one, an enemy a brother only in name**.
>
> I have been killed by thee, O king, who art my brother. For thee, 0 king, I shall enjoy the word widow !My husband should have been saved by thee in the battle. But he was slain by thy ownself in the battle ;art thou not ashamed of this ?"Being thus addressed by his bewailing sister, the Dasagriva, consoling her in sweet words, said "Of no avail is thy lamentation, dear sister; thou needst not be afraid of any of thy relatives.
>
> I shall please thee studiously by gifts, honors and favours. **Being mad after war fare and desirous of acquiring victory,! was continually making a downpour of shafts, so I could not distinguish in the conflict between my own men and enemies, and thus unwittingly I did hurt thy husband. And thus, sister, thy husband was slain by me in the conflict**; I shall now do whatever shall conduce to thy well being.
>
> Do thou ever reside by the side of thy rich brother Khara and he shall be the lord of fourteen thousand Rakshasas. That highly powerful one shall give food and clothes to all those Rakshasas. He is thy cousin and that night ranger shall always carry out thy orders.